Seeking "900 Geometry Problems" Book – Any Leads on Its Whereabouts?
I have been on a quest to find a book titled "900 Geometry Problems" that I've heard a lot about.  The authors are Titu Andreescu and Vladimir Crisan.
Geometry is a subject I am deeply passionate about, and from what I've gathered, this book is a treasure trove of challenging problems and insightful solutions that can significantly aid in my preparation for Olympiad competitions like the RMO and INMO.
Despite my best efforts, I have not been able to locate a copy of this book. It's quite disheartening as I believe this book could be instrumental in enhancing my problem-solving skills and mathematical understanding.
If anyone here knows where I could find this book or has any information about it, I would be immensely grateful. Your help could make a big difference in my contest-preparation journey.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!

I think you heard it a little wrong.
The title is "110 Geometry Problems for the International Mathematical Olympiad" authored by Titu Andreescu & Cosmin Pohoata
Check out :
https://www.amazon.in/Geometry-Problems-International-Mathematical-Olympiad/dp/0988562227
There might be India Prints available , though that is a little unlikely.
